# How to solve conflict among CSS elements?

Tags: css

Have two working documents:

1) modal-standalone: https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/XPOZVy

2) tabs-standalone: https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/VGgQrY

Each works as intended.

Now I want to integrate "tabs" with "modal".

But when I add tabs to modal, the following CSS breaks the integration (see footnote/tooltip #2 in example-3 below)

```
.input-a, section {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

when I remove `section`, I lose the feature where a tab selection brings the target content into view. Here is the instance:

3) modal+tabs: https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/MqLQBq

**How to modify the CSS so that tabs in "tabs+modal" works the same as "tabs-standalone"?**

Comment: Hey, this doesn't look like a CSS issue or I am not understanding your problem. So what's happening is all I see is a loading stuff when I click on footnote 2 in the 3rd version.

Comment: yes, but the combo click-view structure shown in #2 does not work in #3. the content is listed, but not filtered and selectable as in #2